# Problem connecting Cognito form to SharePoint

Tags: cognito-forms

As the title suggests I am trying to connect the form to a SharePoint site. I copied the URL from SharePoint directly to the box provided and have input the correct username/password. A message comes up stating "Cannot Connect invalid Settings" I double-checked the username/password input and they are correct. If I can be pointed in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The most common issue when connecting SharePoint to Cognito is that the URL that is used needs to be the base URL for the SharePoint website or the SharePoint sites sub site address. An example of a correct URL is:

```
http://test.sharepoint.com

https://test.sharepoint.com

https://test.sharepoint.com/{subsite}
```

The URL will work with either http or https, you will not need to include this extra information in the URL "/pages/default.aspx" or "/lists/testlist/". An example of a non working URL is:

```
http://test.sharepoint.com/pages/default.aspx

https://test.sharepoint.com/lists/testlist/
```